# Powershell regex group regex matches but doesn't have my group. What's missing?

Tags: regex, git, powershell

I have some code that I am porting from a jenkins script and I need it as a shell command. So I know the regex *works* - What's blowing my mind is how it can **match** but then not have my capture group. What I need is just the root level directory names as such:

```
foo
baz
```

How can it "match" but then not have my group? BTW: If there is a simpler way to achieve this, I am all ears.

```bsh
PS E:\SysData\Jenkins\workspace\chb0_chb0mb_example> git diff --name-only origin/master  feature/foo |  %{ Resolve-Path -Relative $_ } | sls  '.\\.*\\.*'  | sls '\\.\\(.+?)\\.*|.*' | %{$_.matches}


Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 48
Value    : .\foo\Nuget\deleteme.txt

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 55
Value    : .\baz\QC_OH_DARKESol\deleteme.txt
```

Comment: What does git output?

Comment: `.gitignore`
`Jenkinsfile`
`foo\Nuget\deleteme.txt`
`bar\QC_OH_DARKESol\deleteme.txt`

Comment: As an aside: You can pipe the `git --diff` output _directly_ to `Resolve-Path` - no need for `%` (`ForEach-Object`), which needlessly slows things down: `git diff --name-only origin/master feature/foo | Resolve-Path -Relative`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60250786/45375) points out a potential problem with your approach (`.\\` should be `\.\\`), succinctly demonstrates the unexplained behavior you've experienced (for which they've created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11864)), and suggests a workaround (inserting `| % Line`).

To solve your problem more directly:

```
# Inputs are sample paths.
'.\foo\Nuget\deleteme.txt',
'.\bar\QC_OH_DARKESol\deleteme.txt' | 
  foreach { if ($_ -match '^\.\\([^\\]+)') { $Matches[1] } }
```

The above yields the following strings:

```
foo
bar
```

That is, it *extracts the first path component* following literal `.\` from the input paths, using `foreach` ([`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)) to apply `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) to each input string, whose matching results are reflected in the automatic [`$Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) variable, which is a *hash table* whose `0` entry is the overall match, with entry `1` containing the 1st capture group's value, `2` the 2nd's, ...; *named* capture groups (e.g., `(?<root>...)`), if present, have entries by their name (e.g., `root`).

---

An alternative is to use the [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) with the `-Regex` option:

```
switch -Regex (
  git diff --name-only origin/master feature/foo | Resolve-Path -Relative
) {
  '^\.\\([^\\]+)' { $Matches[1] } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I have the question right.  For one thing, a literal period has to be backslashed.  But it works without backslashing it anyway.  There's no backslash at the beginning.  Not everyone has the git command.  This pattern could be shorter, but it works.  I'm expanding the groups property, which you didn't show.

```
'.\foo\Nuget\deleteme.txt' | sls '.\\(.+?)\\.*|.*' | % matches | % groups

Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 6
Value    : .\foo\

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 2
Length   : 3
Value    : foo
```

Piping the *object* from the first sls to the second sls messes something up with the group capture.  It seems like a bug.  Submitted:  [piping select-string to itself and the strange effect on matches](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11864)  The value property isn't even right here.

```
'abc' | select-string a | select-string '(b)' | % matches | % groups

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 1
Value    : a   # should be b
```

Compare with sending a plain string to the second select-string, which gives the right output:

```
'abc' | select-string a | % line | select-string '(b)' | % matches | % groups

Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 1
Length   : 1
Value    : b

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 1
Length   : 1
Value    : b
```